# LD_LIBRARY_PATH error when calling ssh

Tags: python, ssh, ld, cat

I have a python file in a server. I run the file without any bugs.

But when I run the file via ssh from a different computer,

```
cat hello.py | ssh user@192.168.1.101 python -
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: libcudart.so.7.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Did you install the lib on the remote computer?

Comment: Yes, it works fine on remote computer.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand properly- your hello.py file runs on one server A but not on server B.

server B is the one you are ssh'ing to from wherever.

Your error seems to indicate the environment on server B is not properly set up to execute the hello.py file.  If your servers are running a linux operating system, off top of my head I would compare the

```
/etc/profile
/etc/profile.local
/etc/bash.bashrc.local
/etc/csh.cshrc.local
```

between the working server and the non-working server,
and also do a

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

on each server to observe any differences.
It seems server B does not have the environment set up for the nvidia cuda library, specifically the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.
Or you do not have the cuda library installed on server B.
If neither is the case, then I would look into the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file on server B to see if any environment restrictions are in place preventing a full login environment from happening which is resulting in your problem.

Comment: server B is raspberry pi. Because of the fact that I cannot run cuda on raspberry pi, I need to connect to server A to use cuda, and get the output.

Answer (score 1):

ok,  i think your problem is two-fold.
one is server A which has the Nvidia CUDA is not sending graphics over the network to your raspberry pi, and that may something along the lines of Forward X11 graphics under the sshd configuration on server A.  But if you are using a simple ssh terminal from your raspberry pi then that is also a problem since I don't believe graphics can be displayed via that connection method.
Part 2 which i would bet money on for server A with the nvidia CUDA, is that CUDA wnats to run and display on :0.0 coming out of the graphics card vga/dvi port going to a monitor.  That is display :0.0 and that cannot be redirected over the network without using some 3rd party software; the two i know of that accomplish this are Real-vnc and NxMachine.  I have run into similar problems remote connecting to linux servers with tightvnc and other remote desktop programs, and would get an OpenGL rendering error trying to run software on the server.  This is fixed by having the server run software that can successfully redirect display :0.0 graphics over the network, and then you need client software [on your raspberry pi] that can then display those graphics.